# How I can get the image, which already uploaded?

Tags: laravel, image, image-uploading

Problem is in getting image file, EXAMPLE: create user's profile with name and photo. But after that I want to change name and my EDIT form has two field NAME and PHOTO, but I want to change ONLY NAME, but input file always empty and default value null. So if will not to choose a picture and click submit, then in my db the path to image will change to null. So how I can get image? I read about hash but did not understand how is it to use

Comment: `if(request('image')) //rest of your code` If no image is provided - don't set it.

Comment: check if has a file in request
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    // update photo
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```php
$image = '';

if ($image != null) {
    "Use query upload image" ;
} else {
    "Use query update" ;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer. This is the easiest way